# Derivation of Jump Operators in Master Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, open-quantum-systems

I'm trying to understand the process of deriving the master equation in [this article](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/ab54ac). The system in general is composed of two interacting qubits each of which is coupled to their local thermal bath and both of them are coupled to a common bath. The figure below describes the system.

[image: Scheme of the two qubits interacting with thermal baths]

In section 2.3.1 the authors neglect the interaction between qubits so the system hamiltonian of the two qubits become:

$H_S = \frac{\omega_1}{2}\sigma_1^z + \frac{\omega_2}{2}\sigma_2^z$

which is already diagonal in the ‘canonical basis’ $|00\rangle, |01\rangle, |10\rangle, |11\rangle$ with eigenvalues respectively $E_0 = -\omega_+/2, E_1 = -\omega_-/2, E_2 = \omega_-/2, E_3 = \omega_+/2$ where $\omega_{\pm}=\omega_1 \pm \omega_2$. In order to derive the jump operators we must decompose the system-bath interaction Hamiltonian such that:

$H_I = \sum_{\beta} A_{\beta}(t) \otimes B_{\beta}(t)$

in which $A_{\beta}(t)$ are the system operators. From the interaction Hamiltonian in the article (equation 4 of the article), we see that the system components of the interaction Hamiltonian are $\sigma_i^x$ and $\sigma_i^z$. The jump operators can be found using (equation 17):

$A_{\beta}(\omega) = \sum_{\epsilon'-\epsilon=\omega} |\epsilon\rangle \langle \epsilon| A_{\beta} |\epsilon'\rangle \langle \epsilon'|$

where $|\epsilon\rangle$ are the basis of the eigenvectors of the system Hamiltonian $H_S$ which I have given above. Using this relation, the authors go on to derive the jump operators, stating that:

> In the interaction Hamiltonian we can find the system operators $\sigma_j^x$ and $\sigma_j^z$ coupled to the bath operators, with $j=1, 2$. Their decomposition in terms of jump operators is readily written according to equation (17):

And then they write the jump operators as:

$\sigma_j^x(\omega_j) = \sigma_j^-, \sigma_j^x(-\omega_j) = \sigma_j^+ \rightarrow \sigma_j^x = \sigma_j^- + \sigma_j^+, \sigma_j^z(0) = \sigma_j^z \rightarrow \sigma_j^z = \sigma_j^z$

I didn't understand how they derived this last part. I know that they have used the equation 17 of the article and this is a simple question but for some reason I can't figure out how they did this. For example when I try to find $\sigma_1^x(\omega_1)$ using equation 17, I get:

$\sigma_1^x(\omega_1) = |00\rangle \langle 00|\sigma_1^x |10\rangle \langle 10| + |01\rangle \langle 01|\sigma_1^x |11\rangle \langle 11| = |00\rangle \langle 10|+|01\rangle \langle 11|$

However the text states that $\sigma_1^x(\omega_1) = \sigma_1^-$. I don't know where I have made a mistake. The questions are:

1- What is the step-by-step derivation for the jump operators? Also how do we decide how many transitions are possible and which operators correspond to which transitions?

2- Is it possible to figure out what transitions will we have and to which operators will they correspond before doing these calculations and have a pictorial idea of the problem like figure (b)? I'm asking this because the figure is given before the derivation of the jump operators. So I suspect there is a way to visualize the transitions, the operators corresponding to those transitions and their energies just by looking at the interaction Hamiltonian.

Comment: Note that the authors are using the standard convention $\sigma_1^-:=\sigma_1^-\otimes\mathbb{I}_2$. This means that $\sigma_1^-=|00\rangle\langle10|+|01\rangle\langle 11|$, which is exactly what you have found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am reading the same paper and here is how to derive their jump operators:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.